# What is the meaning of the negative numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I am having troubles understanding what is the "meaning" or best way to think of the negative numbers. I am not really sure where is my confusion, so I would set some examples that make me trouble. Sorry for my informal language.

1. When thinking of "5 - 3" should I think about it as "taking away three elements from five elements" or is it "five positive elements and three negative elements together"? I mean, are negative numbers really numbers (or some quantity) or are they just a natural number under a subtraction operation.
2. From there come I think the rest of my questions. What does "10/-5" really mean? Am I dividing "10 elements" into "five negative groups"? How is that possible? How can there be negative groups?. How can the result be negative, since the elements I am dividing are positive?

I know how to get the results of these cases. But I do not really think I understand what a negative number really mean.

Can anyone help me see where is my confusion and if possible recomend some content to read?

Comment: The preface to Hamilton’s original lectures on quaternions has a *brilliant* philosophic interpretation of rational numbers (signed and unsigned) that will answer your question better than any modern writer is ever likely to.

Comment: The origins is obviously with "negative" quntities : see a bank account. The next step is the usual one with math : generalization. See e.g. Paul Lockhart, [Arithmetic (Belknap Press, 2017)](https://books.google.it/books?id=qX3JugEACAAJ) and Leo Corry, [A Brief History of Numbers (Oxford University Press, 2015)](https://books.google.it/books?id=sFAdCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Here is the link: https://ia601407.us.archive.org/4/items/lecturesonquater00hami/lecturesonquater00hami.pdf

Comment: Related previous questions: [Does a negative number really exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19933/856), [What is a negative number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1328549/856)

Comment: In mathematics everything starts with definition.  How do you define "a number"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I just finished Arithmetic by Paul Lockhart, it was really amazing, I loved the book. I got a better grasp of what a negative number is but I don't really think I have it completely clear. He speaks about "Numbers are what numbers do", that negative numbers are and extension, etc. Do you think I should go into group theory? I'm not sure if my intuition so far is enough to keep on into a more applied subject or if I should get into a more abstract one to understand it in a deeper way?

Answer (score 2):

Numbers don't just correspond with physical objects. We can think of directions as well. Moving one unit forwards +1, or one unit backwards -1. Directing a backwards direction backwards is then tantamount to forwards.

Answer (score 1):

I think of numbers geometrically, equipped with some intrinsic quality of direction. In this view "-" is a unary function that sends a number to one of equal magnitude but opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the natural numbers are given by the Peano axioms. They form a commutative monoid with addition and a commutative monoid with multiplication, where multiplication is distribute over addition.

The next step is then to find the smallest commutative ring contained the set of natural numbers extending their operations. And here you land at the ring of integers.

Comment: Natural numbers existed before Peano (point being, it might not be enough to have an abstract logical model to get an intuitive understanding about something).